# JS: Using window.onload with a function reference

Tags: javascript, html

I try at the moment to re-color a clicked link from purple back to black.

It **works** if I add following code directly into the html file:

```
<script language="javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("url").style.color = "#000000";
};
```

But I dont want to have that function in the HTML instead I put it into my .JS file. But it **doesn't work.**

```
    function changeColor() {
    document.getElementById("url").style.color = "#000000";
    }
```

and then call it like this in the body:

```
<script>
    changeColor(); //doesn't work
    $(document).ready( function () {
        changeColor(); //also doesn't work
    });
</script>
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Can you please include a complete code snippet - for something this simple you should be able to just include the whole thing in stack overflows code tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure that you are using the correct path of javascript file and if you want to use jQuery do not forget that you need the library.

Try this one :

```js
window.init = changeColor();

function changeColor() {
  document.getElementById("url").style.color = "#000000";
}
```

```html
<!-- <script src="js/nameOfYourFile.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->

<a id="url" style="color:purple;" href="#">Hello</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The js file must not have `<script>... </script>`  but pure code

```
   changeColor(); //doesn't work
   $(document).ready( function () {
    changeColor(); //also doesn't work
   });
```

and be   sure you have a proper path in your html for include you js files .

eg :

```
<script src="./myscript.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#url").css("color: #000000");
});
```

make sure you included the file correctly.